# Optimizing many to many sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with many to many relationship, which I join on `userId and then sum/count values so I would get the summary of them. This is how it looks:

```
        select COUNT(DISTINCT [s].[UserId]) AS NumberOfCustomers, 
        sum(s.[ProbabilityAlive]) as ProbabilityAlive,
        avg([s].[ExpectedMonetaryValue]) as ExpectedMonetaryValue, sum(ExpectedTransactions) as ExpectedTransactions,
        sum(s.[CustomerLifetimeValue]) as CustomerLifetimeValue, sum(s.[ResidualLifeTimeValue]) as ResidualLifetimeValue, 
        sum(s.[Transactions]) as Transactions, sum(s.[TotalSpend]) as TotalSpend,
        sum(s.[DeltaProbabilityAlive]) as DeltaProbabilityAlive, sum(s.[ProbabilityActive]) as ProbabilityActive,
        sum(s.[DeltaProbabilityActive]) as DeltaProbabilityActive,
        sum(s.[DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort]) as DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort, sum(s.[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong]) as EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong,
        sum(s.[DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong]) as DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong, sum(s.[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLongLeft]) as EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLongLeft,
        sum(s.[ResidualLifeTimeValueLeft]) as ResidualLifeTimeValueLeft, sum(s.[CustomerLifetimeValueLeft]) as CustomerLifetimeValueLeft,
        SUM(a.PeakClv) as PeakClv
        FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT([Clv].[UserId]), sum([dbo].[Clv].[ProbabilityAlive]) as ProbabilityAlive,
        avg([Clv].[ExpectedMonetaryValue]) as ExpectedMonetaryValue, sum([dbo].[Clv].[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort]) as ExpectedTransactions,
        sum([Clv].[CustomerLifetimeValue]) as CustomerLifetimeValue, sum([dbo].[Clv].[ResidualLifeTimeValue]) as ResidualLifetimeValue, 
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[NumberOfTransactions]) as Transactions, sum([dbo].[Clv].[TotalSpend]) as TotalSpend,
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[DeltaProbabilityAlive]) as DeltaProbabilityAlive, sum([dbo].[Clv].[ProbabilityActive]) as ProbabilityActive,
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[DeltaProbabilityActive]) as DeltaProbabilityActive,
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort]) as DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsShort, sum([dbo].[Clv].[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong]) as EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong,
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong]) as DeltaEstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLong, sum([dbo].[Clv].[EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLongLeft]) as EstimatedNumberOfTransactionsLongLeft,
        sum([dbo].[Clv].[ResidualLifeTimeValueLeft]) as ResidualLifeTimeValueLeft, sum([dbo].[Clv].[CustomerLifetimeValueLeft]) as CustomerLifetimeValueLeft  
        FROM [Clv]  WHERE Clv.[ClientId] = '2' AND   Clv.[CalculationDate] = '02/28/2021' AND  Clv.[Product] = 'Total'  GROUP BY UserId ) s
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  DISTINCT(UserId), SUM([PeakClv]) as PeakClv
            FROM [dbo].[AdditionalClvData]
            WHERE ClientId = '2' AND CalculationDate = '02/28/2021'
            GROUP BY [UserId]
        ) a ON a.[UserId] = s.[UserId]
```

I take almost all values from one table, and one from the other and use pre-aggregating in subqueries. Select from single table takes couple of seconds, however this query takes around 20seconds. Am I doing joining/aggregating incorrectly? Is there a way to optimise so it would work faster?

Comment: Inspect and or post your execution plan (using paste the plan), all performance investigations start with the plan.

Comment: All of your DISTINCT in the query is unnecessary. You can remove them. The first COUNT(DISTINCT ) is actually just a COUNT (*)

Comment: Change `ClientId = '2'` to `ClientId = 2` if `ClientId` is a numerical data type. [Implicite conversions](https://www.sqlshack.com/implicit-conversion-in-sql-server/) can cause performance issues.

Comment: @Sander updated that, but still slow :(